# How can I reuse the escaped value of a query string in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, string

I'd like to reuse a multiple-term search query with `+` for escaping spaces.

$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] results in

```
q=my+search+term
```

while $_GET['q'] results in

```
my search term
```

How can I get

```
my+search+term
```

does it have to be regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$q = str_replace(' ', '+', $_GET['q'])
```

or

```
$q = urlencode($_GET['q']);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
urlencode($_GET['q']);
```

Comment: No, he wants the other way round

Answer (score 1):

No, you can use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$str = str_replace(' ', '+', $str);
```

but if there are more special characters, [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) is the better choice:

```
$str = urlencode($str);
```

Answer (score 1):

$clean = urldecode($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);

http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.urldecode.php